# Make react-native component blink at regular time interval

Tags: react-native, animation, state

I am trying to make a component "blink" on my page. I was thinking about setting a visible: true state in my componentWillMount method and then put a timeout of 1s in componentDidUpdate to set state to the "opposite" of the previous state. As I see it the component lifecycle looks like this :

sets state to visible to true (componentWillMount that runs only once and is not triggering a rerender)
enters componentdidUpdate
waits 1s
hides component (setstate to visible false)
enters componentDidUpdate
waits 1s
shows component (setstate to visible true)

However my component is blinking but the intervals of hide and show are not regular, they change and dont seem to follow the 1s logic

Here's my component code :

```jsx
class ResumeChronoButton extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {

    console.log('in componentWillMount')
    this.setState({ visible: true })
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('in componentDidUpdate')
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible }), 1000)
  }

  // componentWillUnmount(){
  //   clearInterval(this.interval)
  // }

  render() {
    const { textStyle } = styles;
    if (this.state.visible) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}>
          <Pause style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <View style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
};
```

How can I make my component blink at regular time interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      return {
        visible: !state.visible,
      };
    });
  }, 1000);
};

componentWillUnmount = () => {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
};
```

and then your render can just check `this.state.visible` to determine if it needs to show or not.

alternatively you could change the `setState` to

```
this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible})
```

Comment: so if I understand correctly, everytime the component is mounted you create an interval (which acts like a timeout), the state is not touched for 1000ms, then the state changes which triggers the componentWillUnmount where you clear the interval. Is that correct ? I am just wondering why setTimeout is not working in this case ...

Comment: No, that is not correct.  When a component mounts, it will create a create an event using `setInterval` that will trigger every second (`1000 ms`) and update the state (i.e. toggle the visible value).  The clear interval in the `componentWillUnmount`, is preventing a memory leak.

Comment: To answer why `setTimeout` didn't work, is because it is only triggered *once* and you set it up in `componentDidUpdate` which only executes when the `state/props` change (not during initial render).

Comment: Does this work in iOS simulator for you guys. I did example of blinking in GitHub Facebook for react-native. It worked in android well and fine but in iOS I got blank black screen. Any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because you are using the state and timeouts. State is set asynchronously and, for this reason, it may take different amounts of time to change the value depending on how many resources you are using.

To achieve the effect you want I would recommendo you to use the Animation framework from React Native. Check the docs.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
setInterval(()=>{//setstate here},time_in_ms)
```